# php concatenation operator use when operand is a function

Tags: php

```
<?php
function dosomething(){
    echo "do\n";
}

$temp="test".dosomething();
echo $temp;
?>
```

expected result:testdo

but actual result is:
do

test%

I know how to change the code to get the expected result.
But what i doubt is why the code prints result like this.
Can someone explain it?Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dosomething` is echoing to the screen. Since this runs first "do\n" is printed.

`dosomething` also doesn't return anything so the second echo is equivalent to `echo "test";`

In order to use the result of the call you should return it:

```
function dosomething(){
    return "do\n";
}
```

Which will behave as you expect.

To clarify. In order to work out what `$temp` is the function must be run first which prints out "do\n" first.

Answer (score 1):

Use return.

```
function dosomething(){
return "do\n"; }
```

Comment: OP wants: I know how to change the code to get the expected result. But what i doubt is why the code prints result like this. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 1):

Use a return statement instead of echo

```
function dosomething(){
    return "do\n";
}
```

Comment: OP wants: 

I know how to change the code to get the expected result. But what i doubt is why the code prints result like this. Can someone explain it?

Comment: I guess because your function is executed first, so it prints do, and then it print the var $temp which contains test and the concatenation of the function represented by %. You are not agree ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why people are getting down voted. Their answers are right.

http://codepad.org/nagGXY99

Comment: read carefully what OP wants: 
OP wants: I know how to change the code to get the expected result. But what i doubt is why the code prints result like this. Can someone explain it?

Comment: Ah,
There aren't any spaces contained inside the quotes. \n doesn't render out in browsers. &nbsp; will but the only thing that \n or \r or \r\n will render out is in emails and other documents which the PHP is generating content for. 

For instance $foo = 'something'; would return "something" where as $foo = ' something ' ... well you get the idea. You could also include &nbsp; in there but I would recommend against it unless you're directly posting the content to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use return in the calling function. Doing that you will get the string where the function is being called. So function is being replaced by string and 2 strings will then con cat.

-

Thanks